# Touchpad not working after system update (18.04)

Tags: touchpad

I'm not totally sure what happened, but a few days ago, there seemed to be some sort of software update that happened on my laptop that, among also deleting all of my browser cookies, has also made my touchpad not work. I had touchpad-indicator installed as well (a GUI for enabling/disabling the touchpad), but even after uninstalling the problem did not go away.

There have been some similar questions to this, but none of the solutions provided have worked for me so far.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Confirmed that `xinput` shows my Synaptics touchpad by doing xinput in the terminal

ran `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
and replaced

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
```

saved the file and exited, then ran

```
sudo update-grub
```

and restarted my laptop.

I then tried the solution found in [touchpad not working after system update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030124/touchpad-not-working-after-system-update) and restarted my laptop, touchpad still not working.

Now, when I do `xinput`, my touchpad no longer comes up! What should I do?

Comment: I don't know your hardware, but it's likely you're impacted by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798 , the fix is currently in -proposed.  It's my belief you're hit but this 1854798 situation which is different situation to what you linked, so I'd undo what you did following that link & look up the bug report I'm pasting.  I don't know if there are solutions documented here for this Synaptics touchpad issue, but a fix which works for many models exists there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll take a look, this is the most helpful comment I've gotten so far. I'll keep the question as unanswered if somebody else has a potential solution for me

Comment: Update: I also confirmed that I am on the affected kernel version. I managed to undo what I did initially (reverted the change in /etc/default/grub and purged xserver-xorg-input-synaptics from my system, and I now get the following when I do xinput:

⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M510                            id=9 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3336-001                     id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]

Comment: Please add additional information to your question (*you can edit your own questions, questions & answers allow far greater formatting choices and are easier to read, and not everyone reads comments*)

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like it really is caused by the recent kernel update (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798). I'll probably just wait for a stable update. Thanks!